# How can I get camera parameters of save choice

Tags: android

Is there any camera parameters which can show me if it's selected saving to phone memory or if it's selected saving to SD card? I use Action_Image_Capture to take picture. In Action_Image_capture you can choose saving to phone or SD card.

Comment: More details are need. From what perspective?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rawCallback` and `jpegCallback` to grab the data of the image. Then it's up to you where you will store it. You will send in as an argument to your `.takePicture` call.

Ex: `camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);`